# Plot x=y plane in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I fail to think how should I proceed for plotting `x=y` plane withing a 2x2x2 space.

I create a 2x2 meshgrid

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-1:0.1:1,-1:0.1:1);
```

then I come to define `Z` - I get stuck

My thoughts go like this

1. I need to create a 21x21 array for Z ( I use `surf` function.. and the dimensions of X, Y, Z must match. Right?).
2. I need to populate only those values of Z that follow `x==y`
3. Now for each such point i.e. `x==y` Z will vary `-1:0.1:1` .. Does This require that I iterate again and again on the `x==y` and keep drawing Z with values from `-1:0.1:1`?

Am I going the right way about plotting this plane? Kindly help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply need to define `X` and `Z`, `Y` is equal to `X` by definition:

```
[X Z] = meshgrid(-1:.1:1,-1:.1:1);
figure;
surf(X,X,Z);xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z');
```

Results with
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are actually trying to do something two dimensional in a 3 dimensional setting.

A bit unintuitive, but that does not mean it can't be done, for example:

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-1:0.1:1,-1:0.1:1);
Z = zeros(size(X)); % Perhaps you want NaN rather than zeros
idx = X==Y;
Z(idx)=X(idx).^2+Y(idx)  % Of course identical to X(idx).^2+X(idx)
surf(Z)
```

Comment: Note that this plots something in the X==Y plane, rather than just the plane itself.

Comment: This looks cool. It seems idx is storing a logical comparison operation `X==Y` (what do we call such a variable ?)  Then you plot (x,y,X^2+y) only at `x==y` points. Am I correct?

Comment: @vvy That is correct, `idx` is called a logical index.